# Creating a Thread inside a while loop?

Tags: java

So I have a server that accepts socket connections and starts a thread for each socket for data transfer etc. A short sum up of the server code:

```
ServerSocket ss = new SocketServer(7777);
while(true) {
    Socket socket = ss.accept();
    Runnable r = new aHandler(socket);
    new Thread(r).start();
}
```

Now I have two questions knowing that variables get destroyed after every loop,  is the Thread still alive after a loop? And if it does is the socket closed after the loop or is it still running inside the Thread?

Comment: Any reason you don’t just use http and a embedded web server?

Comment: The thread keeps itself alive until it terminates (usually naturally).

Answer (score 0):

Yes too both the socket connection will stay open and the thread will continue to run. For this kind of situation it will be the threads job to close its self. Or else the threads will take more and more ram the more connections you make.

Answer (score 0):

Right, if the server accepts the connection, it can delegate the interaction with the client right away into a new Thread, thus, accepting new connections. Connections stablished and delegated to a Thread will end smoothly when they get closed.

You can check exactly that scenario explained in Java Tutorial here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html#later

and a working example here:

**Server supporting multiple clients:**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KKMultiServer.java

**Thread handling connections once it is delegated to it:**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KKMultiServerThread.java

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those threads would be alive. The thread that spun would actually enters your run method and it would continue to execute that.